# sql ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

please help

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MERC_ADM_VERSION )then UPDATE MERC_ADM_VERSION SET
VER_VALEUR = 20150409 WHERE VER_CLE = 'MEAD' ELSE   INSERT INTO MERC_ADM_VERSION
('VER_VALEUR', 'VER_CLE') VALUES (20150409, 'MEAD');
```

ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement

Comment: `IF` isn't part of Oracle SQL; it's part of the PL/SQL syntax. Perhaps you're looking for a `MERGE` statement?

Comment: Where did you leard Oracle SQL? Find a book or referance for Oracle SQL statements.

Comment: Try here : https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from the columns in the insert statement.

Instead of

```
 ('VER_VALEUR', 'VER_CLE')
```

It should be

```
(VER_VALEUR, VER_CLE)
```

Comment: Is this in a stored procedure or function? IF is part of PL-SQL, you cannot write it as normal query.

Comment: That is a problem, but it isn't causing the ORA-00900 error.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear as to what you are trying to do.  However, my best interpretation is you are looking for an oracle merge statement.  Below is an example based on assumptions I made on the little information you provided.  You are most likely looking for a MERGE statement.  This allows you to perform a single operation that can either update or insert based on your criteria.

Also, you appear to be using a date, but in number format.  I did nothing to address this due to lack of any table definition.  You may still have problems with it.

```
MERGE 
INTO merc_adm_version TARGET  -- The table you want to update/insert into
USING (SELECT 20150409 as ver_valeur, 'MEAD' as ver_cle FROM dual) SOURCE  -- The source of the data
ON    (TARGET.ver_cle = SOURCE.ver_cle)  -- How to try and match records between source and target
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ver_valeur = 20150409  -- When there is a match, how to update
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ver_cle, ver_valeur)  -- When there is not a match, how to insert
                      VALUES ('MEAD', 20150409);
```